# View all posted data?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I'm looking for a development method to use AMPscript (or?) to view all data posted to an AMPscript form processor. I had done something similar a while back in PHP but don't have access to the system I was working on. Seeking a simple function that might display all the posted data data on the forms action destination.

Comment: Did you find an answer to this? I need to access everything sent in the request, each client can post different data, so cannot use RequestParameter("Forename") for example? Am new to ET and AMPScript, so hopefully have missed something simple!

Comment: Hey Lordy! It's been 6 months since I last worked in exact target and now that I'm filling my brain back up with PHP apparently I didn't have room to keep all of the AMPscript in my "mental RAM".  If I recall the solution was to QueryParameter for each variable and along with posting them to the Data Extension also displaying them on the resulting landing page. I no longer have access to that system or I'd look it up for you. - good luck (Kelly?)

Answer (score 1):

Documentation for Microsite and Landing Page AMPscript is located [here](https://help.exacttarget.com/en-US/documentation/exacttarget/content/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/microsite_and_landing_page_ampscript_functions/).

You would want to use something like `QueryParameter()` or `RequestParameter()`, and request the information from the form you require.

These functions behave much like `$_POST` would in PHP.

Comment: What I had in mind would mimic this type of script from the land of PHP. {<?php print_r($_POST); ?>} which would display all posted content on the page. The difference of course being that if I don't request or query correctly I may not see my results coming through. So my guess is that AMPscript has nothing like that and your suggestion factors that I'll need to ask for specific data and see "if" it came through within the application. Correct?

Comment: Is the difference that a query only parses data through a URL but a Request can parse from a URL OR a Post? No method to just display the full array posted? (in other words we need to request specific info, it won't just display all posted data)